# flexbox related css not taking effect

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is my first post on this website so please forgive any formatting/ etiquette issues etc. I have recently learned flexbox on TeamTreehouse and decided to make a project to apply my new knowledge. The project takes heavy inspiration from http://stylus-lang.com/. The project (atleast the way it theorized it) seemed simple at first in terms of objectives)

- Two column layout using a main column that takes up around 70% of the viewport while the other column takes 30%
- first/main column will have its own scrollbar
- Second column will simply be a list  that serve as links
- using flexbox make columns responsive and at a smaller viewport breakpoint make the second list column merge into a single column layout with the list column on top to serve as a header with its own separate scrollbar (look at http://stylus-lang.com/)

```css
/* ================================= 
  Web Fonts
==================================== */

@font-face {}


/* ================================= 
  Base Element Styles
==================================== */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
}

h1,
h2,
p {
  color: rgb(224, 169, 96);
  font-family: Arvo;
  rgb(224, 169, 96);
  text-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em 0.25em #000000;
  /* 2px 2px 4px*/
}

.logo-pic {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}

.logo-text {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  color: text-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em 0.25em #000000;
  /* 2px 2px 4px*/
  text-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em 0.25em #000000;
  /* 2px 2px 4px*/
}

.logo-info {
  text-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em 0.25em #000000;
  /* 2px 2px 4px*/
}

.card {
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 1em;
}


}

/* ================================= 
  Base Layout Styles
==================================== */

/* ================================= 
  Media Queries
==================================== */
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .col {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1025px) {}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> Marksman Mains</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="primary col ">
      <div class="logo-banner">
        <img src="Css/Adcs/Marksman_icon.png" alt="" class="logo-pic">
        <h1 class="logo-text">Marksman Mains </h1>
        <h2 class="logo-info"> A Quick Source For Every Marksman's All in One Guide including Up-To-Date item builds, Runes, and laning/playstyle advice. </h2>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <h1> Test Card</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h1> Test Card</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h1> Test Card</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h1>Test Card</h1>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--Primary-->



    <div class="secondary col ">
      <section>
        <aside>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li>Ashe</li>
            <li>Caitlyn</li>
            <li>Corki</li>
            <li>Draven</li>
            <li>Ezreal</li>
            <li>Jhin</li>
            <li>Jinx</li>
            <li>Kai'Sa</li>
            <li>Kalista</li>
            <li>Kog'Maw</li>
            <li>Lucian</li>
            <li>Miss Fortune</li>
            <li>Sivir</li>
            <li>Tristana</li>
            <li>Twitch</li>
            <li>Varus</li>
            <li>Vayne</li>
            <li>Xayah</li>
          </ul>
        </aside>
      </section>
    </div>
    <!-- Secondary -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem so far is that I can't display anything using flex. 
I'm not supper well versed in flexbox, but so far what I have been trying to do is get the list items column and the main column to show side by side, the only thing I have to go on at the moment is when a container is displayed as flex the defualt should set the direction as row, but it doesn't seem to be happening.

Any advice will be highly appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Put your code in the question, keeping in mind the advice in [mcve]

Comment: fixed code formatting and improved title (a bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an extra `{` before the media query and also updated the media query correctly.

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .col {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
}

h1,
h2,
p {
  color: rgb(224, 169, 96);
  font-family: Arvo;
  text-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em 0.25em #000000;
}

.logo-pic {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}

.logo-text {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  color: text-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em 0.25em #000000;
  /* 2px 2px 4px*/
  text-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em 0.25em #000000;
  /* 2px 2px 4px*/
}

.logo-info {
  text-shadow: 0.125em 0.125em 0.25em #000000;
  /* 2px 2px 4px*/
}

.card {
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 1em;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .col {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> Marksman Mains</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>



  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="primary col ">
      <div class="logo-banner">
        <img src="Css/Adcs/Marksman_icon.png" alt="" class="logo-pic">
        <h1 class="logo-text">Marksman Mains </h1>
        <h2 class="logo-info"> A Quick Source For Every Marksman's All in One Guide including Up-To-Date item builds, Runes, and laning/playstyle advice. </h2>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <h1> Test Card</h1>

      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h1> Test Card</h1>

      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h1> Test Card</h1>

      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h1>Test Card</h1>

      </div>





    </div>
    <!--Primary-->



    <div class="secondary col ">
      <section>
        <aside>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li>Ashe</li>
            <li>Caitlyn</li>
            <li>Corki</li>
            <li>Draven</li>
            <li>Ezreal</li>
            <li>Jhin</li>
            <li>Jinx</li>
            <li>Kai'Sa</li>
            <li>Kalista</li>
            <li>Kog'Maw</li>
            <li>Lucian</li>
            <li>Miss Fortune</li>
            <li>Sivir</li>
            <li>Tristana</li>
            <li>Twitch</li>
            <li>Varus</li>
            <li>Vayne</li>
            <li>Xayah</li>


          </ul>



        </aside>
      </section>
    </div>
    <!-- Secondary -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```